# Get summary grouped by category with three tables on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

```
category
---------------------------
id_category     primary key
category    
id_user         foreign key

counterpart
---------------------------
id_counterpart  primary key
counterpart
id_category     foreign key
id_user         foreign key

transaction
---------------------------
transaction     primary key
date
id_counterpart  foreign key
amount
id_card         foreign key
id_user         foreign key
```

Hello,

I have thoses table on mysql database and i want to have summary of each category (with 0 if there is any transaction) by month and year based on id_user.

I tried this command to have grouped by counterpart and it works but cannot reach when i add category and group by id_category.

```
select counterpart, s2.total from counterpart as s1
left join (select coalesce(sum(amount),0) as total, id_counterpart from transaction where year(date) = 2019 and month(date) = 7 and id_user = 2 group by id_counterpart) as s2
on s1.id_counterpart = s2.id_counterpart
left join category on s1.id_category = category.id_category
group by counterpart;
```

Do you have any idea to do that ? Else, i will do with php.

Thank you.

---

Edit : Add example

```
INSERT INTO `category` (`id_category`, `category`, `id_user`) VALUES
(1, 'cat_a',    1),
(2, 'cat_b',    1),
(3, 'cat_c',    1);

INSERT INTO `counterpart` (`id_counterpart`, `counterpart`, `id_category`, `id_user`) VALUES
(1, 'cp_a', 1,  1),
(2, 'cp_b', 2,  1),
(3, 'cp_c', 2,  1);

INSERT INTO `transaction` (`id_transaction`, `date`, `id_counterpart`, `amount`, `id_card`, `id_user`) VALUES
(1, '2019-07-01 00:00:00',  1,  400.00, 2,  1),
(2, '2019-07-01 00:00:00',  1,  -24.95, 2,  1),
(3, '2019-07-31 00:00:00',  2,  -20.04, 2,  1);
(4, '2019-07-30 00:00:00',  2,  -1.00,  2,  1);
(5, '2019-07-29 00:00:00',  3,  -2.00,  2,  1);
(6, '2019-07-28 00:00:00',  1,  -3.00,  2,  1);
(7, '2019-07-27 00:00:00',  3,  2.00,   2,  1);
(8, '2019-07-26 00:00:00',  2,  5.00,   2,  1);
```

On july 2019 i want to have this, for user 1 :

```
cat_a       372.05
cat_b       16.04
cat_c       0.00
```

Comment: As you asked me, I have added some data and what I expect to have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the tables and then group by category:

```
select c.category, coalesce(sum(t.amount), 0) total 
from category c
left join counterpart as cp 
on c.id_category = cp.id_category and c.id_user = cp.id_user
left join transaction t 
on t.id_counterpart = cp.id_counterpart and t.id_user = cp.id_user and year(t.date) = 2019 and month(t.date) = 7 and t.id_user = 1
group by c.id_category, c.category
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hTbpuiXVYbaUV1W4VfFDCF/2).
Results:

```
| category | total  |
| -------- | ------ |
| cat_a    | 372.05 |
| cat_b    | -16.04 |
| cat_c    | 0      |
```

Comment: I have multiple user from id_user 2 and id_user 1 (category and counterpart) is for every user. This way it works on your demo but i should have to limit on id_user  of transaction table, i guess.

Comment: `select c.category, coalesce(sum(t.amount), 0) total 
from category c
left join counterpart as cp 
on c.id_category = cp.id_category
left join transaction t 
on t.id_counterpart = cp.id_counterpart and t.id_user = cp.id_user and year(t.date) = 2019 and month(t.date) = 7 and t.id_user = 2
where c.id_user = 2 or c.id_user = 1
group by c.id_category, c.category`

Comment: Just an update `SELECT c.category, COALESCE(SUM(t.amount), 0) total 
FROM category c
LEFT JOIN counterpart AS cp 
ON c.id_category = cp.id_category
LEFT JOIN transaction t 
ON t.id_counterpart = cp.id_counterpart AND year(t.date) = 2019 AND month(t.date) = 8
AND c.id_user in (1, 2) AND cp.id_user IN (1, 2) AND t.id_user = 2
WHERE c.id_user IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY c.id_category, c.category;`